# How to find the length of argv[] in C

Tags: c, argv, strlen, strcat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fir; //badly named loop variable
    char *input[] = calloc( strlen(argv), sizeof(char)); //initializing an array
    for( fir = 1; fir< strlen(argv); fir++){ //removing the first element of argv
        strcat(input, argv[fir]); // appending to input
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is for line 7. It says "passing argument 1 of 'strlen' from incompatible pointer type". I get the same error for the `strcat` function.
It also says "given a `char **` but expected a `const char *`" for both functions.

I'm trying to populate a new array with all the elements of `argv` except the first. I tried `argv = &argv[1]` and it did not work.

Do the `strlen()` and `strcat()` functions not take `char` arrays?

Comment: I think you want an index into that `argv[]`, but don't go outside `[0..(argc-1]` when you do.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

`argv` is an array of pointers to `char` (i.e. array of strings). The length of this array is stored in `argc` argument.

`strlen` is meant to be used to retrieve the length of the single string that must be null-terminated else the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I think I understand. I cannot use argv[] because it is not actually an array of char, an array of pointers to char's? if I make a copy of argv[x] and use it in strcat like strcat(input, copyargv[x]) will that work?

Comment: argv[ ] is an array of strings (i.e. an array of pointers to char pointers, where each char pointer points to the beginning of a string);
argc tells you how many strings you have;
strlen returns the length of the passed in string, so it can only be called on a char *, i.e. char [ ], i.e. string): strlen(argv[i]), where i is between 0 and argc.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure why no one has suggested changing strlen to refer to a specific entry in the array of pointers to char?

```
 strlen(argv[0])     // also, 1, 2, up to (argc - 1)
```

Also, http://www.cdecl.org/ helps in confirming that the `char *argv[]` statement is: `declare argv as array of pointer to char`

Answer (score 3):

```
int count = 0; 
while(argv[++count] != NULL);
```

Now, count will have the length of argv

Comment: `!= NULL` is not needed. You could just do something like `while(argv[++count]);`

Comment: Doesn't this only give you `argc`? You are counting the number of arguments, not the total length of the string run by the user.

Answer (score 2):

`argv` is an array of `char*`. The size of this array is `argc`. You should pass an element of this array to `strlen`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to do something like this:

```
size_t argv_length(char** argv)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    while( *(++argv) )
        ret += strlen(*argv);

    return ret;
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is an array of char, `strlen` only takes strings. If you want to get the length of each argument in `argv` (which is what I was trying to do), you must iterate through it, accessing the elements like so `argv[i][j]`. Using the argument `argv[i][j] != '\0'`. If you just want the number of arguments use `argc`.

Answer (score 0):

you can drop this into your main, easy peasy, keep it simple :

```
int argvlen = 0;

while(argv[argvlen] != NULL){

   // NOTE: argvlen++ increment postfix.   
   printf("argv[argvlen++] = %d\n", *argv[argvlen++]);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

argv takes an arryas of char* but you need to pass argc to strlen rather than whole the array.
Then you wont get any error on strcat.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int fir; //badly named loop variable
char *input[] = calloc( strlen(argc), sizeof(char)); //initializing an array
for( fir = 1; fir< strlen(argv); fir++){ //removing the first element of argv
 strcat(input, argv[fir]); // appending to input
}
```