# How to find small string in big string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

trying to create a code in C. First of all, I **can't** use the string.h library or any other that helps similarly. The input will be from command line like: ./program pattern file, I already succeed to open the file and write line of the file to an array, but now I have to compare the pattern a get with the line in file. If there is written the pattern, I have to printf the whole line.

For the input I use:

```
char array[1000]; // hope 1000 will be enough

char *pattern= argv[1];
```

For the scanning I use:

```
while (fscanf(f,"%c", &temp)!= EOF){
        if (temp=='\n'){
             Algoritm...
        }
        add to array( array[i++]=temp) - already works`
```

And If I get end of line, I do not When the '\n' ocures, I need to start the algorithm to find out if the small string is in the line.

My questions:

How can I compare these "strings"? efficiently?

How to get know the size of pattern I get as input? (I think I need that to do the algorithm)

Comment: scanning `%c` is not efficient either, use `fgetc`

Comment: There are [many functions in standard C dealing with characters and strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). I'm sure you'll be able to find a function that [finds a substring](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr).

Comment: as for the "I can't use `<string.h>`"... you *know* what function you could use *if* you could use it, i.e. `strstr`, then google for *"strstr c implementation site:stackoverflow.com"*

Comment: I surely can, but I can't use any. That's the problem.

Comment: If you know which function *could* be used, then it's very easy to use its name to find tutorials and examples on how to use it. For example searching for `strstr c example` or `strstr c tutorial`.

Comment: I understand you, and your functions, but I can't use any library in this work, so any of the funtions you sent me cannot be used..

Comment: I guess, you don't really understand what is suggested. If you search for the implementation of a given function you can add your own version of that function to your project. No library involved.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are working on linux.

For your first question.
memmem() should find the needle in your haystack;

From the memmem() manpage:

> The memmem() function finds the start of the first occurrence of the
>   substring needle of length needlelen in the memory area haystack of
>   length haystacklen.
>
> memmem returns:
>
> The memmem() function returns a pointer to the beginning of the
>    substring, or NULL if the substring is not found.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmem.3.html

For your second question:
[How to find the length of argv[] in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649547/how-to-find-the-length-of-argv-in-c)

Comment: This isn't an answer. The question states *"I can't use the string.h library or any other that helps similarly."* And your second part directs the reader to another question, with no actual solution proposed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own find function.

```
int find(char *array, char *pattern) {
    char *ap, *aap, *pp;
    for(ap=array; *ap; ap++) {
        for(pp=pattern, aap=ap; *aap && *pp && *pp==*aap; aap++, pp++); 
        if(*pp=='\0') return ap-array;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The outer loop loops over your line 1 char a loop. It's the start point for the compare in the inner loop. The inner loop loops over your pattern and the line while

- pattern not at end
- line not at end
- pattern char equals line char

without loop body.

If the pattern end is reached it was found and the function returns the found position in the line.